# iOS development, show UIScrollView area on top of current view

Tags: iphone, ios

Has anyone used the Instagram app lately?

It has a very neat feature, where, while you are using camera, you can touch the 'eye' button, which pops up a small scrollable UI area that contains different filters that can be applied to the camera video.

Can anyone help me on what kind of UI element I should use to get such popup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one on the Instagram app looks like a simple UIScrollView with custom subviews added in.  What these subviews contain and how they look is completely up to you and your design.